# appcompat-v7:25.3.0 : AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, . }

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting the following error while running and the activity does not start. The error is showing at `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` Please help.

I am using the following libraries:

```
compile project(':library')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.5'
compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0-javadoc.jar')
compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-core-slh_3.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-core_3.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-manipulation_3.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
compile files('libs/parse-android-1.13.3.jar')
compile files('libs/ParseCrashReporting-1.9.1.jar')
compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.0.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
```

The error is:

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: com.app.android.hashmap, PID: 26336
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.android.hashmap/com.app.android.hashmap.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
>                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:474)
>                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:328)
>                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:289)
>                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                                at com.app.android.hashmap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android developers have made AppCompat more restricted about `windowNoTitle` flag as they were introduces [AppCompatDialogs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html) which are highly dependent on `windowNoTitle` flag - in version of `22.1.0`.

**So to fix your problem use your theme parent to - `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`**

If your requrement doesn't suite that, use separate theme where needed -

For example -

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    ...
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.NoActionBar">
    <!-- both your properties are there -->
    <!-- Remove other ones.. i.e. windowActionBarOverlay and all -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Reference - [Android developer's blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)

Comment: Thanks @kiranbennyjoseph and wizard. It worked like a charm.

Comment: This didnt work for me. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

set this only in your theme found in styles.xml and 
delete this.

```
android:windowIsFloating: false
windowActionBarOverlay: false
windowActionBar: false
```